# Why a component? Drawer of mui Does not work inside Iframe

Tags: reactjs, iframe, material-ui, drawer

I'm trying to enter drawer into `Iframe` in the component of react And for some reason it doesn't show it to me In the `Iframe` When I look in the `dev tools` the `<body>` that within the `Iframe` is empty.

This is the code snippet:

```
      <iframe>
        <Drawer open={open} onClose={toggleDrawer(false)}>
          <List>
            <ListItem disablePadding>
              <ListItemButton>
                <ListItemText primary={'nenu'} />
              </ListItemButton>
            </ListItem>
          </List>
        </Drawer>
      </iframe>
```